# If using Django-tenat-schemas how to flush database?

Tags: python, django

I am using django-tenant-schemas app to handle tenants and database related to various tenants. Now what I want to do is flush all the database so how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any django command on a per-schema basis using the tenant_command wrapper, if you want to iterate all schema's you'll have to create a custom command that iterates all tenants

```
./manage.py tenant_command flush --schema=customer1
```

*source: http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#tenant-command*

Comment: Why the downvote..?? As far as I can understand, he is asking about how to flush the DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am working with https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants, but this should also work for https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas.

When using multiple tenants/schemas, flush does not work anymore. When you use `manage.py flush`, the error tells you that there are foreign key constraints that are not met; and it suggests:

```
HINT:  Truncate table "<your table name>" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

Here is a management command (`flush_cascade.py`) which does that (I only tested with PostgreSQL`):

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.commands.flush import Command as FlushCommand
from django.db import transaction

class Command(FlushCommand):    
    @transaction.atomic
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        options['allow_cascade'] = True
        call_command('flush', *args, **options)
```

Django's default [flush](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/flush.py) command only sends `TRUNCATE` to the database. It doesn't add `CASCADE` because not all database backends support cascading statements.